# Quickest c++ GUI creation

Tags: c++, user-interface

I'm working on a visual c++ project and I have decided to implement it using GUI. Now, the problem is that I don't really have want to learn something entirely new for the GUI creation as I'm already learning c# and would like to carry on with c# GUI rather than c++ GUI.

So, I want a quick way to create GUI for the visual c++ project.

PS: I already know Java, if that can be used.

Platform: Windows 8/ 7/ Vista
Cross-platform: doesn't matter
Current ide: Visual Studio 11 Ultimate
current os: Windows 8 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

You can try MFC. I find it has lower learning curve if you already use MS stuff, than other GUI options (QT, WTL, ...)

Otherwise, you can create GUI in C# and use interop to run your C++ components behind it, or you can even try C++/CLI where you will get a .NET assembly written in C++ (actually, something very similar to C++) which is then simply referenced from your GUI assembly.

Comment: Can you suggest some MFC getting started tutorial?

Comment: well, if you google "MFC GUI tutorial" you will surely find a lot of useful stuff.

Comment: +1 from me - if you use MFC and make a dialog app, that will be the fastest way to a drag-and-drop GUI, but it won't be anything pretty.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want something very quick you could use Python to create the GUI. It compiles under the hood to C++ and so it can interact with a C++ library very well, and the GUI creation is less verbose than C++. However programming a C++ GUI is not really "something new" when compared to just using C++ in general.

The various frameworks/libs (DirectX, OpenGL, Qt etc...)  all have their own feel, but it they are C++.

You could also use C# to create your GUI to a C++ lib if you want and you could use Java via JNI. In other words the world is your oyster.

Comment: Is there no drag-and-drop way to create gui (something similar ti java swings)?

Comment: There are in the various IDEs. I'm pretty sure that you can get one for Eclipse and MS Visual Studio. Google it for options.

Comment: Is there any way to create gui in Java for a c++ program? I know is is not advisable, but I'm very short on time.

Comment: Yes... using JNI to call the desired functionality, but if you are short on time I would avoid JNI as it is not the easiest thing in the world to use.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll go with resEdit